# Array Index operator overloaded.Unable to use the comparison operator now

Tags: c++, overloading

I overloaded array subscript ( [] ) operator. I have made it return an integer as I wont be using it for any assignment purposes. However, I am unable to use the comparison operator now!

Here is the code

```
class Set
{
public:
    virtual int operator[](int i) = 0;
    virtual int size() = 0;

    void union_operation(Set* second);
    void interesction_operation(Set* second);

};

void Set::union_operation(Set* second)
{
    int second_size = second->size();
    for(int i=0;i<second_size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<this->size();j++)
        {
            //The line below doesnt work!
            if(this[j]==second[i])
            {
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The implementation of operator overloading is carried out in a derived class.

Since the overloaded operator will return an integer, hence the comparison is between two integers, which is perfectly valid. Why does this line still give an error?

Comment: `(*this)[j]==(*second)[i]` P.S: You should take that parameter by reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, `this` is a pointer that requires dereferencing before you can use it. Unless you're passing it to a function of course.

So, in order for your comparison to work, it should look like the following:

```
if((*this)[j] == (*second)[i])
{
    break;
}
```

EDIT: `second` is also a `Set` pointer so you must dereference it to use it too.